# AJAX sends to PHP, and receives and success messsage, but PHP page itself takes the else statment, doesn't work. 2 different acts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

this is the html page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="big2">

        <ul id="navmenu">
            <li class="mainnav"><a href="#">Software Dep</a><span class="darrow">&#9660;</span>
                <ul class="sub1">
                    <li><a href="#">Level One</a><span class="rarrow">&#9654;</span>
                        <ul class="sub2">
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2One"> Semeter One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2Two"> Semester Two</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level Two</a><span class="rarrow">&#9654;</span>
                        <ul class="sub2">
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2One"> Semeter One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2Two"> Semester Two</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level Three</a><span class="rarrow">&#9654;</span>
                        <ul class="sub2">
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2One"> Semeter One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2Two"> Semester Two</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level Four</a><span class="rarrow">&#9654;</span>
                        <ul class="sub2">
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2One"> Semeter One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2Two"> Semester Two</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="mainnav"><a href="#">Network Dep</a><span class="darrow">&#9660;</span>
                <ul class="sub1">
                    <li><a href="#">Level One</a><span class="rarrow">&#9654;</span>
                        <ul class="sub2">
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2One"> Semeter One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2Two"> Semester Two</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level Two</a><span class="rarrow">&#9654;</span>
                        <ul class="sub2">
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2One"> Semeter One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2Two"> Semester Two</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level Three</a><span class="rarrow">&#9654;</span>
                        <ul class="sub2">
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2One"> Semeter One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2Two"> Semester Two</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level Four</a><span class="rarrow">&#9654;</span>
                        <ul class="sub2">
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2One"> Semeter One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="sub2Two"> Semester Two</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this is the ext.js script
//all this script is doing is when i hover on the titles in the navigation bar it takes the values from them and store them in variables, dep,level,semester, and it works.

```
$('.sub1').hover(function(){
    dep = $(this).prev().prev().text();
    $('#dep').text(dep);
});

$('.sub2').hover(function(){
    level = $(this).prev().prev().text();
    $('#level').text(level);
});

$('.sub2One').click(function(){
    semester = 'Semester One';
    $('#sem').text(semester);
    sendData();
});

$('.sub2Two').click(function(){
    semester = 'Semester Two';
    $('#sem').text(semester);
    sendData();
});


function sendData(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'processSyllabus.php',
      data: {'semester': semester,'level':level,'dep':dep },
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
  });
}
```

this is the processSyllabus.php page

```
 //whatever i do, it always echo "Not Set" though the alerted data is the variables and not "Not Set", how is that happening!
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['dep']) && !empty($_POST['dep']) && isset($_POST['level']) &&      !empty($_POST['level'])  && isset($_POST['semester']) && !empty($_POST['semester']) ){
echo $_POST['dep'].' '.$_POST['level'].' '.$_POST['semester'];
   }else{
 echo '<br>Not Set ';
  }             
  ?>
```

Comment: So it always returns "<br>Not Set ", no matter what data you send to the server?

Comment: i've spent 2 days just trying, always the PHP page returns "<br>Not Set " and the alert is the variables correctly

Comment: And why did you remove the php code? It might be relevant.

Comment: i just added the comment to it

Comment: That's crazy. I've copied your code, assigned string values to the variables before sending them because I did not copy the html to evaluate and it works just fine. Are you sure the variables are all filled correctly?

Comment: Or are you maybe just trying to only send some data to the server at a time? Because it the if statement is configured to only execute when all three values are set and not empty on every request.

Comment: it assigns the values each time, but only send them together as i choose the semester, could it be the browser or anything like that? coz im out of ideas !

Comment: Try alerting all three variables right before doing the ajax request to make sure none of them is empty.

Comment: i've done that, and they have values

Comment: This thing is driving me crazy. Now i copied your whole project, not just parts of it, and it still works perfectly: [Example on my server](http://stuff.raptilic.us/test/semesters/)

Are you sure you don't have a little spelling error in your actual project that you didn't carry over here?

Answer (score 1):

Try to access the data this way:

```
var_dump( json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")) );
```

You are sending a JSON, this is not accessible trough $_POST. You need to read raw data from the request body using php://input.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: Yup.   $JSON = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); Then $JSON->dep is your reference to the data.

Comment: His JS and PHP always worked. Just hitting the page directly always showed "not set" because there was nothing being posted. $_POST/$_GET from his original code always worked. But this is handy, I will keep it in mind as another way to get data =).

Answer (score 0):

A first step would be to take a look at what your browser is sending to the server.  One way would be to print it to a log file on the server before you get to the if.

Another way is to check what's leaving the browser.  Here's how to do it in Firefox (and the other browers have similar tools available):

1) Open the Network Developer Tool (ctrl-shift-Q - or menu, Web Developer, Network)

2) Load the html/js page.

3) On the far right, near the top of the grey developer tool area is a little expander thing.  When you hover over it it will say 'show request details'.  Click on that.  That will show you Headers, Cookies, etc

4) click sub2One or sub2Two

5) You'll see the request go out to your php page.  Click on that request and examine Headers, Cookies, etc.  Knowing whether its client side or server side is the first step.

Comment: Dr Black has your path.  Something like $JSON = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
Then $JSON->dep is your reference to the data.

Answer (score -1):

data: {'semester': semester,'level':level, 'dep':dep }

If you're sure everything is posting correct from the JS the PHP below might help to see everything being sent and what is not being set.

```
<?php

     print_r( $_POST );
     print_r( $_REQUEST );

     if( $_POST['dep'] && $_POST['level'] && $_POST['semester'] ){
          echo $_POST['dep'].' '.$_POST['level'].' '.$_POST['semester'];
     }else{
          echo '<br>Not Set ';
     }             
?>
```

I think the problem was a little code and understanding that **when POSTING to processSyllabus.php the results are different than viewing it directly**. We changed to use $_GET and added the vars to the querystring to make sure the page was working and I think it solved the problem.

Does this make sense? With **POST** you will get different results than hitting the page directly because you are looking for something to be posted. When we changed to **GET** the variables are coming from the URL when hitting the page directly so the else statement is not entered.

I shoud have read the title a little more "**AJAX sends to PHP, and receives and success messsage**, but **PHP page itself takes the else statment, doesn't work**. 2 different acts"

Read comments below for results.

Comment: JavaScipt does not care whether or not you use quotation marks for the keys, so this should make no difference.

Comment: Sorry, thought it might help if they were not set. Looks like you would have to click all 3 buttons for all 3 values to be set.

Comment: no, i just have to hover over the first two selections, its a drop down navigation bar, and when i click on the semester, it should sends everything

Comment: and they are global so i dont have to define them again to set them again with each time

Comment: before the ajax call what is the alert( semester + ' ' + level + ' ' + dep ); ? I don't see dep being set anywhere in the JS

Comment: sorry it looks like i didn't copy it, it alerts the correct semester,level,dep that i have chosen, i mean everything is defined before the ajax call and correct

Comment: hmmm, added some PHP that might help. Looks strange for sure.

Comment: i edited the PHP page and this is what it says

Array ( ) Array ( ) 
Notice: Undefined index: dep in E:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\schedule\processSyllabus.php on line 6

Not Set

Comment: that was from the PHP page,
in the alert it says:
Array
(
    [semester] => Semester One
    [level] => Level One
    [dep] => Software Dep
)
Array
(
    [semester] => Semester One
    [level] => Level One
    [dep] => Software Dep
)
Software Dep Level One Semester One

Comment: yay, then just remove both the print_r =)

Comment: its not what you think, the PHP page is saying this *** Array ( ) Array ( ) Notice: Undefined index: dep in E:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\schedule\processSyllabus.php on line 6 Not Set

*******
but the alert from the ajax call is saying this *****
 Array ( [semester] => Semester One [level] => Level One [dep] => Software Dep ) Array ( [semester] => Semester One [level] => Level One [dep] => Software Dep ) Software Dep Level One Semester One
******

Comment: this is my problem, each one is doing a different thing ! its really strange

Comment: i even tried : 


    $.post('processSyllabus.php',{'semester':      semester,'level':level,'dep':dep }, function(data){
      alert(data);
     } );

Comment: same thing, 'Not Set' in the PHP page, and all set when it alerts !

Comment: Yes, the PHP page will need the values passed in or give a warning from trying to access an undefined index in the array. You can turn off warnings, supress it with a @ before or check the array index to be sure it exists.

Comment: If you remove both the print_r lines or just comment them out. Then try the JS page again and your alert should be "Software Dep Level One Semester One".

Comment: Check out what the browser is actually sending to PHP (see my answer)

Comment: i added the @ it just did show the warning, and echoed "Not Set"

Comment: It will always show "not set" unless you use the AJAX call or post to it some other way.

Comment: Hey Mark, his alerts are returning "Array ( [semester] => Semester One [level] => Level One [dep] => Software Dep ) Array ( [semester] => Semester One [level] => Level One [dep] => Software Dep ) Software Dep Level One Semester One" with the PHP above.

Comment: Dr Black has it correct.  See his answer.  I put how you'd use it in mine, but he has your solution.

Comment: hmmm, but when he print_r both the $_REQUEST, $_POST and final result were printed ... weird you would have to get them another way when he gave the result himself a couple comments up ...

Comment: im just a benginner, i dont know how to use jason_decode :/.
is there any other way that i can get them, i've tried $.get and $.post and the ajax, they're all not working

Comment: though i've used all 3 of them in some other stuff that i made and they work just fine, i don't know what's wrong this time, everything isn't working

Comment: If you want to use both the page by it's self and the AJAX call then use GET rather than POST. In the AJAX use GET, then in the PHP use $_GET, then if you want the page to work by it's self you will have to do something like processSyllabus.php?dep=Software_Dep&level=Level_One&semester=Semester_One

Comment: yeah it i did it this way and it worked but it will refresh, i dont want it to refresh

Comment: That's good it's working. What do you mean refresh? Only use processSyllabus.php?dep=Software_Dep&level=Level_One&semester=Semester_One by it's self to view the page. The AJAX call is still only processSyllabus.php.

Comment: where would i put that then?       processSyllabus.php?dep=Software_Dep&level=Level_One&semester=Semester_One

Comment: That link is just to view the page to be sure it was working =). It was using $_POST so the page would always be "not set" unless you call it with an AJAX post or POST to it another way, but $_GET will get variables from the querystring so you could see the page working.